# Kendo UI for Angular: Tooltip on a grid cell with external content

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-tooltip

[Here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/knowledge-base/show-grid-cells-content/) it is described how to put a tooltip on a kendo grid cell. However it is only about tooltip containing some information from the anchor element, for example its *title* attribute. But what is the best way to integrate external information not available at the anchor? In my case I want to have a tooltip displaying the name of the last editor of the grid item when I hover over a particular cell of it. The name is not part of the cell content. It comes additionally from the backend for each grid row. How can I access it for the tooltip?

```html
<kendo-grid [height]="200"
            [data]="myModel">
  <kendo-grid-column field="one" title="First column" width="90"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="two" title="Second column" width="60"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="three" title="Third column" width="120"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: I am not able to access the data model of the grid row inside the tooltip directive or template, I understand. I have access to the HTML anchor element only.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code.

Comment: I didn't try anything. I thought about using some hidden columns/cells where I could load the required data and then access it using DOM selectors starting from the cell where I want to display my tooltip. I think that could work for me but it sounds very cumbersome...

Comment: So, I wanted to ask the community first, before I start doing some crazy stuff :-)

Comment: Please post some code to make it easier for the community to help you. You can use https://stackblitz.com/ to create a simple demo.

Comment: I added how my grid looks like now. But it is just a normal kendo grid, nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved it. The solution was to modify the kendo column with ng-template:

```html
<kendo-grid-column title="My titel" width="90">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                  <span kendoTooltip title="{{dataItem?.tooltipContent}}">
                    {{dataItem?.cellContent}}
                  </span>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

This way I "smuggle" the external data to the cell HTML element. Then it can be easily accessed with kendo tooltip directive.